# Set Validation settings(Formula and User Message) using PnP powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Can someone help me how can i set the **Formula** and **User message** on the Validation settings of a Sharepoint Online List using PnP powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below sample script for your reference:

```
connect-pnponline https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael

$list=get-pnplist "TestList"

$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$list.ValidationFormula="=LEN([Title])<6"

$list.ValidationMessage="Test message!"

$list.update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! you saved lot of my time.